# Artistic source code: Hello World

Tags: ascii-art, popularity-contest, obfuscation

Back to basics! Create a "Hello World" program which prints, well, "Hello World". The winner this time though, is the one who gets the most interesting source code done. For instance, use obscure language features, make it obfuscated, or make the source code a peom or a piece of ASCII art. Your imagination and coding ability are the only limitations.

- Print `Hello World` (exactly so)
- Make sure your source code is... unique. Yeah, that.

To obey the FAQ, I can't just decide what I think is the best, thus the winner will be the one getting the most votes, and I will select an answer during the **first day of May**.

Comment: Between http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world and http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/hello-world-0-0, we've seen chances to do this same work before, nor is the metric of the problem well defined.

Comment: @dmckee: This is a creativity challenge, thus it might occur as illdefined.

Comment: Every good question we have here is a creativity challenge. Every single one. You make think of that as a operational definition of a good contest.

Comment: @dmckee: Ok, sorry.