# Guess my Number - Code Golf

Tags: code-golf

The puzzle is as follows:

Create the traditional 'Guess my Number' game in as little keystrokes as possible. The player should input a guess between and including 1 and 100, and the computer should reply with either `+` (meaning the player needs to guess higher), `-` (meaning the player needs to guess lower) or `=` (meaning the player has guessed the number. The game continues until the player has guessed the number. The number that the computer generates MUST be a random number between and including 1 and 100.

#### Sample gameplay

```
50
+
75
-
60
-
55
+
57
=
```

Happy Golfing!

Comment: Whoever can post an answer fastest with the OSK in most OSes gets my vote. That's like, 3 keystrokes to open

Comment: @Howard this one is basically a simplified version of the one you found. Not an exact duplicate, though

Comment: @JanDvorak, I feel its not a significant enough variant to warrant a different question.

Comment: @zzzzBov how does that work on a puzzle site, this is a slightly different question though I agree it's pretty close. However the other one has an accepted answer. what if people want to work this puzzle but not the other one?

Comment: @ryan, I don't know how it works on a site such as [CodeGolf.SE]. [I fully understand the predicament of posing a challenge similar to an existing one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1536/hello-world-0-0), however in this case, I feel that this one is too similar to the existing one. It's an opinion, and in the end the votes are what will decide whether or not this gets closed or stays open.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Ruby: <s>63</s> <s>58</s> <s>52</s> 49 characters

```ruby
puts"=-+"[r=$_.to_i<=>n||=1+rand(100)];r==0&&exit
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ ruby -ne 'puts"=-+"[r=$_.to_i<=>n||=1+rand(100)];r==0&&exit'
50
-
25
+
37
+
43
-
40
+
42
=
```

Comment: A few small improvements: `exit if r==0` -> `r==0&&exit`, and there is no whitespace needed in `puts"=-+"`.

Comment: I remembered the `&&` trick just this morning. Seems I'm getting slow.

Comment: Ups, sorry. I read the code wrong.

Comment: Is `1+$$%100` random enough?

Comment: +1 for [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28number%29#Popular_culture) as a random number :)

Answer (score 9):

**Python <strike>84</strike> 83 characters**

```
import os
a,c=0,ord(os.urandom(1))%100+1
while c-a:a=input();print'=-+'[c!=a:][c>a]
```

Comment: I can not make it work with python 3. Here is my solution

```import os
a,c=0,ord(os.urandom(1))%10+1
while c-a:a=int(input());print("not ok")
print("ok")```

Comment: Can you please try to run your code?

Answer (score 6):

**Perl <strike>57</strike> <strike>53</strike> 50 (thanks to @manatwork) Characters**

```
$_=qw(= + -)[$^T%100+1<=>$_];print"$_
";exit if/=/
```

Note You need to invoke with `-n` option

Alternate version as suggested by @primo

**Perl 40 Characters**

```
$_=chr 44-($^T%100+1<=>$_||exit print'=')
```

Comment: `qw(= - +)` is shorter than `('=','-','+')`

Comment: @manatwork: I am not a perl expert. Thank you for the advise :-)

Comment: You not need `while`, `if` is enough. And please change the response logic.

Comment: @manatwork: I think you can use this answer to post a new one (you deserve it). Once you are done, I will delete it. As I said am not an expert of Perl :-)

Comment: Just keep it. I really like the `$^T` trick. (Note to myself: it's time to read `man perlvar` again.)

Comment: Bit of a re-work, but essentially the same for 41 (actually 40, because `^T` can be replaced with character 20), requires `-pl`: `$_=chr 44-($^T%100+1<=>$_||exit print'=')`

Comment: @primo's suggestion makes me wonder whether would count as rule bending to use `die"=\n"` instead of `exit print'='`. After all, the question says “the computer should reply”, but no restriction on how.

Comment: @primo: I am not incorporating your suggestion as because that would amount to a different answer altogether. But in any case I need to learn more of perl :-)

Comment: @Abhijit I can't post it separately either, because it's basically a copy of yours ;)

Comment: @primo: How about if I delete it? The Best should rule :-)

Comment: @Abhijit or just add it as an alternate. That would be my preference.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 52

```
for(u=r=1+new Date%100;u=r-prompt(u<0?'-':'+'););'='
```

Just paste it in the console.

Comment: Nice one! Even if skips some of the rules: uses 0..99 interval instead of 1..100 and not displays “=” on success.

Comment: @manatwork now I guess I can read the rules :) I edited for the 1..100.

Comment: @manatwork I edited for the `=` too. Much less elegant. I'll try later to make it shorter.

Comment: You can save 1 character by using a reference to `prompt()`: first `p=prompt`, then just `p()`. But something is wrong with the logic, as the “=” only appears if you guess the number on first try.

Comment: I must leave for a moment. But this version should work (less user friendly, though).

Comment: Nice one, +1! Btw, you can save two more characters by doing "u=r=1+new Date%100" as we don't really care about starting value of u.

Comment: @XzKto Right. I edit :)

Comment: I was unsuccessful at making it shorter, but I did find an alternate expression for `u=r-prompt(u<0?'-':'+');` if someone wants to try and explore it further: `u=r-prompt('+-'[u<0|0]);`.

Comment: I had found this one, and a very similar I used in some iterations for distinction between 0 and not 0 : `'=+'[u/u|0]`.

Answer (score 5):

### APL (28)

```
{'='≠⎕←'+=-'[2+×⎕-⍵]:∇⍵}?100
```

Comment: I can't read this, but it looks cool.

Answer (score 3):

**C#: <strike>147</strike> 136 Characters**

It won't beat most other languages, but here's a C# solution for fun:

```
var r=new Random().Next(1,100);var g=0;while(g!=r){g=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());Console.WriteLine(""+g+'\n'+(g<r?'+':g>r?'-':'='));}
```

Comment: Is that a complete C# program source ?

Comment: I remember seeing a post on meta about ignoring standard overhead/bloat from languages like C#/Java (can't find the link now). It will copy-paste into LINQPad.

Comment: If you remove overhead from other, they'll be shorter too. The Go one for example could be reduced to 105 chars. But it would be hard to define a unique line, so I don't think that really makes sense.

Comment: You can trim another 27 by changing your definition, loop handling, and unnecessary echo of the input.  `int r=new Random().Next(1,100),g=0;while(g!=r){g=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());Console.WriteLine(g<r?'+':g>r?'-':'=');}`

Comment: Your code will never choose the number "100", it should be Next(1,101) or Next(100)+1. :)

Comment: You can reduce it to 131 by declaring both variables in the same sentence: `int r=new Random().Next(1,101),g=0;while(g!=r){g=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());Console.WriteLine(""+g+'\n'+(g<r?'+':g>r?'-':'='));}`

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 128

Won’t be winning any awards, but here it is.

```
main=fix.(.)(=<<(read<$>getLine)).f=<<(`mod`100).fst.next<$>newStdGen where p=putStrLn;f y r x|x<y=p"+">>r|x>y=p"-">>r|True=p"="
```

Ungolfed logic and imports:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Function
import System.Random

main :: IO ()
main = do
  random <- newStdGen
  let number = fst (next random) `mod` 100
  fix $ \loop -> do
    guess <- read <$> getLine
    check number guess loop
  where
    check number guess loop
      | guess < number = do
        putStrLn "+"
        loop
      | guess > number = do
        putStrLn "-"
        loop
      | otherwise = putStrLn "="
```

Answer (score 2):

**C89 <strike>92</strike> <strike>90</strike> <strike>89</strike> (Thanks to @ugoren) 84 characters**
*running on OS and linked with Linker supporting [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)*

```
main(c,g){g=g/8%100+1;while(scanf("%d",&c)&&printf("%c\n",g-c?"-+"[c<g]:'=')&&c-g);}
```

Comment: I don't think that will produce very random numbers in many OSes, unless address space randomization is turned on.

Comment: @fluffy: I already mentioned in my most. And IMHO, all modern OSes except RTOS supports ASLR

Comment: `main(c,g)` would save `int`. Or maybe `main(g,c)`, assuming the argument vector is randomized by ASLR.

Comment: However, ASLR will not randomize the low bits.The address of `main` will always be a multiple of 4 (at least).

Comment: @ugoren: Yes I agree and so changed my code accordingly. On another context I have not acceoted your edit, cause the particular bahaviour of missing type defaulting to int is not accepted in C99.

Comment: 1. Are you forced to use C99? If older C helps you shorten it, why not? 2. change `while` to `for`, and use the initialization part to save a character. 3. `'='` -> `61`.

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure (117 characters)

```
java -jar clojure.jar  -e "(loop[n(int(*(rand 100)))]((get{-1#(prn '+)0#(do(prn '=)(System/exit 0))1#(prn '-)}(compare(eval(read))n)))(recur n))"
50
+
75
+
90
-
86
-
82
=
```

### Clojure (74 characters)

Guessing a real number. Nobody will be patient enought to solve to "=", so nobody notice the missing exit.

```
java -jar clojure.jar  -e "(loop[n(rand)](prn (get{-1 '+ 0 '= 1 '-}(compare(eval(read))n)))(recur n))"
0.5
+
0.8
-
0.6
+
0.7
+
0.75
-
0.72
+
0.74
+
0.745
+
0.748
-
0.746
-
0.7455
-
...
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>89</s> 85 chars

```
s=sample(1:100,1);while(s!=(a=as.real(readline())))cat(ifelse(a>s,"-","+"));cat("=")
```

Comment: +1 putting the user guess in the while condition is indeed a good idea! However defining `cat` as a variable here actually cost you 2 characters: `w=cat;` (6) + 2 times `w` are 8 characters while 2 times `cat` is only 6 characters! :) I think you can also get rid of the curly braces since your `while` loop now contains only 1 line.

Comment: @plannapus Good points! The `w=` made a lot more sense when I was using `write`, but your way is better.

Answer (score 1):

### K, 69

```
b:1b;g:1+*1?100;while[b;-1(*$[g<f:"I"$m:0:0;"-";g>f;"+";("=";b:0b)])]
```

Could definitely be golfed more

```
k)b:1b;g:1+*1?100;while[b;-1(*$[g<f:"I"$m:0:0;"-";g>f;"+";("=";b:0b)])]
50
+
75
-
60
+
65
-
63
+
64
=
```

Answer (score 1):

## Tcl, 96 chars

```
set n [expr int(rand()*100)+1];while {[gets stdin g]&&$g!=$n} {puts [expr $g<$n?"+":"-"]};puts =
```

Ok, and now guessing a real number (91 chars):

```
set n [expr rand()*100+1];while {[gets stdin g]&&$g!=$n} {puts [expr $g<$n?"+":"-"]};puts =
```

And here a small script to test this: (Solver)

```
set fd [open "| /usr/local/bin/tclsh hilo.tcl" RDWR]
fconfigure $fd -buffering none
lassign 0\ 100 + -
while 1 {
    puts "-> [set new [expr {(${-} - ${+}) / 2. + ${+}}]]"
    puts $fd $new
    gets $fd in
    puts "<- $in"
    if {$in in {+ -}} {set $in $new} break
}
```

Change the `2.` to `2` for integers.

Answer (score 1):

## Go, 152

Golfed :

```
package main
import(f"fmt";"os")
func main(){
c:=1+os.Getpid()%100
u:=0
for u!=c{
f.Scanf("%d",&u)
s:="="
if u<c{s="+"}else if u>c{s="-"}
f.Println(s)}}
```

Ungolfed :

```
package main

import (
    f "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    c := 1 + os.Getpid()%100
    u := 0
    for u != c {
        f.Scanf("%d", &u)
        s := "="
        if u < c {
            s = "+"
        } else if u > c {
            s = "-"
        }
        f.Println(s)
    }
}
```

Session :

> guess
>
> 4
>
> +
>
> 88
>
> -
>
> 66
>
> +
>
> 77
>
> -
>
> 71
>
> +
>
> 73
>
> +
>
> 75
>
> =

Hard to golf when you start any program with `package main` and a list of imports...

Comment: But real golf has big bags full of heavy clubs. There are even wheels on the bags. What's more they are "imported" for you by your caddy. And you drive around a big, reserved field in electric carts. Let's not even speak about the annual fee.

Answer (score 1):

### R: 88 characters

```
r=sample(1:100,1);i=scan(n=1);while(i!=r){cat(ifelse(i<r,"+","-"));i=scan(n=1)};cat("=")
```

Ex:

```
> r=sample(1:100,1);i=scan(n=1);while(i!=r){cat(ifelse(i<r,"+","-"));i=scan(n=1)};cat("=")
1: 23
Read 1 item
+
1: 46
Read 1 item
-
1: 35
Read 1 item
-
1: 31
Read 1 item
-
1: 28
Read 1 item
+
1: 30
Read 1 item
-
1: 29
Read 1 item
=
>
```

Comment: Look at my answer; this can be shortened by (1) defining a `cat` variable and (2) defining `i` in the `while` loop. You can also use the `quiet` option to remove the "Read 1 item" notice, but I don't think you can turn off `scan`'s "1:" prompt.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP: <strike>95 91 87 73 71</strike> 65 chars

```
<?php $n=rand(1,100);while(@$g!=$n){$g=trim(fgets(STDIN));echo$g==$n?'=':($g>$n?'-':'+')."\n";}
<? for($n=rand(1,100);@$g!=$n?$g=trim(fgets(STDIN)):0;)echo$g==$n?'=':($g>$n?'-':'+')."\n";
<? for($n=rand(1,100);$n!=$g=trim(fgets(STDIN));print(($g>$n?'-':'+')."\n"));echo"=\n";
<? for($n=rand(1,100);$n!=$g=fgets(STDIN);print(($g>$n?'-':'+')."\n"))?>=
<? for($n=rand(1,100);$n!=$g=fgets(STDIN);print($g>$n?'-':'+')."\n")?>=
```

```
<?for($n=rand(1,100);$n!=$g=fgets(STDIN);print$g>$n?"-
":"+
")?>=
```

Comment: 89: `<? for($n=rand(1,100);($g=trim(fgets(STDIN)))!=$n;print$g==$n?'=':($g>$n?'-':'+')."\n");`

Comment: You don't need to call `trim`, since `8 == "8\n"`. That brings it down to 81 characters: `<? for($n=rand(1,100);$n!=$g=fgets(STDIN);print(($g>$n?'-':'+')."\n"));echo"=\n";`

Comment: You can get it down to 73 characters by exiting PHP mode at the end instead of calling `echo`: `<? for($n=rand(1,100);$n!=$g=fgets(STDIN);print(($g>$n?'-':'+')."\n"))?>=`

Answer (score 1):

## C: 86 characters

```
i;main(r){r+=(7*time(0)+3)%100;while(scanf("%d",&i)&&puts(i<r?"+":i>r?"-":"=")&&i-r);}
```

It is well-behaved, implements a simple LCG and compiles under both Clang (Clang is much more picky than GCC) and GCC.

Answer (score 1):

### R 70

```
n=sample(1e2)[1];while(n-(g=scan(n=1)))cat(if(n>g)"+"else"-");cat("=")
```

Answer (score 1):

VB.net      146

`Dim r,g As Integer:Dim s As String:r=New Random().Next(1,100):Do Until g=r:g=InputBox(s):If g<r Then s="+" Else If r=g Then s="-" Else s="="
Loop`

Comment: Your code will never choose the number "100", it should be Next(1,101)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript (<strike>75</strike> **74** chars):

```
for(n=1+Math.random(a=alert)*100>>0;(g=+prompt())-n;)a('+-'[+(g>n)]);a('=') 
for(n=1+Math.random(a=alert)*100>>0;(g=+prompt())-n;)a(n>g?'+':'-');a('=')
```

Numbers are actually random

Answer (score 0):

## J: 64 characters

```
r=.>:?100
while.(t=.{&'<=>'>:*-&r".(1!:1)1)~:'='do.t(1!:2)2 end.t
```

Doing I/O in J is sort of bulky compared to the rest of the language.

Answer (score 0):

**vbScript <strike>115</strike>  110**

<strike>Randomize:dim n,r,s:r=(Int)((100*Rnd+1)*2):do until(r=n*2):n=inputbox(s):If(n*2>r)Then:s="-":else:s="+":end if:loop</strike>

```
Randomize:dim n,r,s:r=Int(100*Rnd+1)*2:do until r=n*2:n=inputbox(s):If(n*2>r)Then:s="-":else:s="+":end if:loop
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mathematica 66**

```
n=RandomInteger@100;For[,(i=Input[])!=n,Print@If[n>i,"+","-"]];"="
```

Answer (score 0):

### vba, 95

(immediate window)

```
randomize:z=int(rnd()*100)+1:while q<>z:q=cint(inputbox(q)):?iif(q<z,"+",iif(q>z,"-","=")):wend
```

Comment: You can use `Int` instead of `CInt`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

### GWBASIC, 104

```
1 RANDOMIZE TIMER:Z=INT(RND*100)+1:WHILE Q<>Z:INPUT Q:IF Q<Z THEN ?"+" ELSE IF Q>Z THEN ?"-"
2 WEND:?"="
```

(just because I can)