# Scrolling Marquee

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Following my entry to the [Obfuscated Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3695/2764) I thought it might be fun to share the underlying code. But why just show the code, lets make it a golf too!

**Challenge**

Write a script that scrolls a string across the terminal, from right to left, settling on the left side.

**Input**

Takes a string as an argument.

**Result**

Prints the scrolling marquee to STDOUT. Max width of ~50 chars. Starts with 0 or 1 char showing. Some space between letters while scrolling. Stops when settled (having no extra space between word chars). Slow scroll, but not too slow (< 1s per iteration).

**Example**

Running script with arg `'Hello World'`

```
                                                   H
```

later

```
                H    e    l    l    o         W    o
```

later

```
H    e    l    l    o          W    o    r    l    d
```

later

```
Hell    o         W    o    r    l    d
```

finally

```
Hello World
```

For a running example, try my code from the "Hello World" challenge. <s>Eventually I will post mine. It currently is 202 chars in Perl.</s> Now that there are some competitors, I have posted mine in the answers.

**Winner**

I don't want the restrictions to be absolute, that's why I left them a little vague. The shortest script which follows the spirit of my original will win.

**Notes**

This game assumes `xterm` environment. Should another environment prove useful, only similar environments will be compared and a separate winner may be declared for each.

**Addendum (April 25, 2012)**

To address some budding issues, I'm making a ruling. Your character count must include code needed to:

1. Flush STDOUT (Looking at you Ruby)
2. Implement `sleep` with time delay of <1s (Looking at you Perl)

This may be done as command line switches to an interpreter, but those characters count in the total (sans surrounding whitespace).

Comment: I'm a little concerned about terminal behaviors for this kind of thing...`xterm`, `vt102`, ...?

Comment: I'm assuming xterm, but I don't think it matters too much. Perhaps I don't understand your concern?

Comment: These tricks are usually produced by relying on the way various terminals handle some of the non-printing characters, and terminals differed in what they could do and what sequences produced the effects. For reproducibility it might be good to have a specified terminal environment.

Comment: It'll serve you right is someone posts a *really* short answer that depends on an obscure terminal that you don't have an emulator for, but OK.

Comment: ok I think I have it now. Thanks for the thoughts :-)

Answer (score 5):

### python 2 - 146 chars

edit: made it a function instead of input through stdin. first argument is the string, and the second argument is the length you want it to be. so invocation would be `f('Hello World', 50)`. I also made it much smoother; when each character 'landed' there was an awkward pause

```
import os,time
def f(x,n):
 y=' '*n+'  '.join(x);z=0
 while y:w=y[0]==x[z];y=y[1+w:];z+=w;os.system('cls');print((x[:z]+y)[:n]);time.sleep(0.1)
```

old, 158 chars:

```
import os,time,sys
x=' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
y=' '*50+'  '.join(x)
z=0
while y:z+=y[0]==x[z];y=y[1:];os.system('cls');print((x[:z]+y)[:50]);time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Using bash (at least in a recent installation of MacOSX and CentOS), the shell command used to clear the terminal screen should be 'clear' not 'cls'.

Comment: 'cls' for windows, 'clear' for OSX/Linux builds, I guess

Comment: Advice how to start the program for those not dealing with python on a daily basis, would be helpful. Start python. paste code, call `f("Hello World, 40)` worked for me.

Comment: @user I um. I did put invocation up there?

Answer (score 4):

#### Ruby, <strike>93</strike> <strike>91</strike> 89 chars

```
u="\1";s=u*50+[*$*[0].chars]*(u*3);$><<s.tr(u," ")[0,50]+" \r"while s.sub!u,""*sleep(0.1)
```

The text to be displayed must be given as command line argument, e.g.

```
ruby marquee.rb "Hello World"
```

for the example shown above. Unfortunately I cannot show the animation here, so you have to try out the code yourself.

*Previous version:*

```
s=" "*67+[*$*[0].chars]*"   ";(s.size*3/4).times{|j|s[j/3]='';$><<s[16,50]+" \r";sleep 0.1}
```

Comment: Impressive size. Its not very smooth though, is that me (I'm on a pretty low-power machine at the moment) or is that how the code works?

Comment: Figured it out, I had to set `STDOUT.sync=true;` so that it autoflushes. The Perl equiv is `$|++`. Thats an additional 17 chars, but still well below mine. Well I can't have Ruby beating Perl! Gonna hafta get working. Nice one.

Comment: If I call `ruby1.8 "Hello World"` I get, not exactly to my surprise, an error saying: `ruby1.8: No such file or directory -- Hello World (LoadError)`

Comment: @userunknown maybe you should put the path to the source file in there, too: `ruby foo.rb args` ;-)

Comment: @padde: Yes, I should. Unfortunately Howard edited his post without informing me about his change. Have a look at the history to understand my question.

Comment: @userunknown i understand, sorry for that.

Comment: @Howard +1, this is really nice. I tried really hard to shave off a char here and there but this is the best it gets.

Comment: @JoelBerger: It's very jumping for me too. Just 4 pictures, before the String reaches the final position, reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

### C, <strike>94</strike> <strike>83</strike> <strike>80</strike> 173 chars

EDIT: Added lots of code, implements all the requested functionality now.
The constant `1e8` can be tweaked to control the speed. On my machine, it's quite fast as it is.
Some characters can surely be saved here. `l` can be static (saves initialization), `c` can become a pointer (replacing `b+c`).

```
char b[99],c=1;
main(a,t,w,i,l)char**t;{
    for(l=0;b[l++]=*t[1]++;b[l++]=32);
    for(w=80;i--||
        printf("\033[F\033[K%*.*s\n",w-=l<a,a++,b,i=1e8)>l+6||
        b[++c]&&memmove(b+c-1,b+c,l););
}
```

Old version (80 chars), with partial functionality:
Saved a couple of chars by replacing `char**t` with `int*t`. Works fine in 32-bit (`int**t` would support 64-bit).

```
main(i,t,w)
    int*t;
{
    for(w=80;i--||printf("\033[F\033[K%*s\n",w,t[1],i=1e8)*--w;);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### K&R C -- <s>431</s> 416 characters

Respects the standard to a high degree. Uses ncurses so it should be largely terminal independent. There is a slight stuttering when the text hits the side due to some trickery played to preserve the intended whitespace in the string.

The string to use should be passed as the first argument on the command line (and should be escaped if it contains spaces, more so if it contains a `!` as my test string (`Hello, World!`) did).

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define T usleep(1e5),S(l)
#define U mvprintw(23,0,"%s",l),refresh()
char l[63],*p,*q,r;
S(char*s){r=0;if(*s==32)q=s++;else{for(;*s-32||*(s+1)-32;s++); 
for(q=s;*s==32;s++);(s-q)&1?s--:usleep(1e5);}
for(r=0;*s;*q++=*s++){*s-32?r=1:0;}return r;}
main(int c,char**v){initscr();curs_set(0);for(c=0;c<62;l[c++]=32);
for(p=*++v;*p;){l[52]=*p++;U;T;U;T;U;T;}for(;T;U);getch();endwin();}
```

In a more readable and commented form:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char l[63] /* take advantage of 0 initialization */,
  *p,*q, r;

/* Remove the first unwanted space. Unwanted means at the begining of
 * the line, all of even length blocks between non-spaces, and
 * all-bu-one of odd length blocks between non-spaces.
 *
 * Return true if the removed space occurs before a non-space character.
 */
S/*lide marquee*/(char*s){
  r=0; /* initialize the return value */
  if(*s==' '){
    q=s++;
  } else {
    /* Find the start of first block of contiguous spaces */
    for(;*s-' '||*(s+1)-' ';s++); 
    for(q=s;*s==' ';s++); /* q holds the start, s finds it's end */
    /* if this block is even length remove all, if odd, all but one */
    if( (s-q)%2 )s--; else usleep(1e5);
  }
  /* copy from s to q all the way to the end */
  for(r=0;*s;*q++=*s++){ 
    if(*s-' ')r=1; /* note if we pass a non-space */
  } 
  return r;
}

main(int c,char**v){
  initscr();curs_set(0); /* setup ncurses with invisible cursor */
  for(c=0;c<62;l[c++]=' '); /* initialize l */
  for(p=*++v;*p;){ /* load the message into the marque, skipping space */
    l[52]=*p++;
    mvprintw(23,0,"%s",l),
    refresh();
    usleep(1e5),
    S(l);
    usleep(1e5),
    S(l);
    usleep(1e5),
    S(l);
  }
  for(;usleep(1e5),S(l);mvprintw(23,0,"%s",l),refresh()); /* keeping sliding until we're done. */
  getch();
  endwin();
}
```

Comment: There's lots of potential for shortening, especially by replacing `if` with operators. For example - `if((s-q)%2)s--;else usleep(1e5);` -> `s-q&1?s--:usleep(1e5);` (or `s-=s-q&1||usleep(1e5);`)

Comment: @ugoren: Yup, and I had forgotten to replace the `' '`s with numeric equivalents.

Comment: A few more tricks: Replace `x==32` with `x-32` (reverses meaning, so reverse if-else), or with `x<33` (assuming 0..31 never used). Initialize with values you have (`for(curs_set(c=0);...`). `*(s+1)`->`s[1]`. Remove unneeded braces (replacing `;` with `,` will help).

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5.13.2, 96

```
$_=join$;x4,$;x46,split//,pop;print substr(s/$;/ /gr,0,50)." \r"while$|=s/$;//+select'','','',.1
```

Stealing a lot from @[Kevin Reid](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3994/kevin-reid)'s answer, especially the `/r` trick available in newer Perls.

### Perl, 115

Like @[Joel Berger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2764/joel-berger)'s answer, this would become much shorter if I could use `sleep 1` and be slow, or pass `-MTime::HiRes=sleep` on the command line to enable `sleep.1`.  Otherwise the only built-in way to get short sleeps is `select'','','',.1` which is pretty long.

```
$|=@_=(($")x45,map{($")x4,$_}split//,pop);for(0..$#_){print@_," \r";splice@_,($_-=45)<0?0:$_/4,1;select'','','',.1}
```

#### <s>Perl, 128</s>

```
$_=$"x9 .pop;s/./    $&/g;$.=-46;$\=" \r";while($|=/./g){print substr($_,0,50);pos=++$.<0?0:$./4;s/\G.//;select'','','',.1}print
```

#### <s>Perl, 133</s>

```
$|=@_=split//,pop;for$i(reverse-$#_..50){for(@_){print$"x($j||$i),$_;($i+=$j=($i++>0)*4)>50&&last}print"    \r";$j=select'','','',.1}
```

Comment: yeah, I bit myself with my own rule on that one! I didn't realize that other langs would have a usleep built in. Oh well.

Comment: some suggestions, you can remove the space after each `x` and the block form of `map` will save a few.

Answer (score 2):

### bash 234

```
w=$1
p(){
i=$1
s=$2
p=$((50+s*3-i))
((p<s+1)) && p=$((s+1));
((p<50)) && echo -en "\e[20;"${p}H$3"  ";
}
clear
for i in {0..99}
do
for s in $(seq 0 ${#w})
do
p $i $s ${w:s:1} 
done
sleep .1
echo -en "\e[20;1H  "
done
echo -en "\b\b$w\n"
```

Usage:

```
./marquee.sh "Hello, fine marquee world"
```

ungolfed:

```
#!/bin/bash
w=$1
p(){
    #si String index
    it=$1
    #it=iteration
    si=$2
    pos=$((50+(si*3)-it))
    ((pos<si+1 )) && pos=$((si+1));
    ((pos<50)) && echo -en "\e[20;"${pos}H$3"  ";
}
clear
for it in {0..99}
do
    for si in $(seq 0 ${#w})
    do
        p $it $si ${w:si:1} 
    done
    sleep .1
    echo -en "\e[20;1H   "
done
echo -en "\e[22;1H"
```

Comment: It's not working on `Ubuntu 20.04 bash version 5.0.17`.

Comment: Yes, there where some `\e` missing, I don't know whether my error in transmition or maybe some database update in the last 9 years.

Comment: Awsome! It works.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript <del>180</del> 218 chars

Production Version:

```
function f(){i--&&(i>50?h=h.substr(1):h=h.replace(" ",i==16?"&nbsp;":""),document.body.innerHTML="<pre>"+h.substr(0,50)+"</pre>",setTimeout(f,99))}h=(new Array(50)).join(" ")+"HelloWorld".split("").join("   "),i=80,f()
```

Ungolfed Version:

```
h=new Array(50).join(" ")+("HelloWorld".split("").join("   "));
i=80;

function f(){
        if(i--){
            if(i>50){
                h=h.substr(1);
            }else{
                h=h.replace(" ",(i==16)?"&nbsp;":"");
            }
            document.body.innerHTML="<pre>"+h.substr(0,50)+"</pre>";
            setTimeout(f,99);
        }
}
f();​
```

Here is a [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fYvg7/3/)

**Note:** if you try to reproduce it, make sure the code is below the body

Comment: I can't tell from the demo, does it "stack up" on the left side, or simply make it to the left and then show the final string? Howard's definitely works if you are unsure.

Comment: @JoelBerger the hello world have 4 spaces between each letter, when the h is the first character, these spaces are removed. This demo is slower http://jsfiddle.net/fYvg7/1/

Comment: That's close, but you should remove each space individually.

Comment: @JoelBerger Fixed

Comment: Well I hate to be a nag, but one other problem: yours starts with all the letters showing rather than entering one-by-one on the right.

Comment: @JoelBerger No problem, I already had that, I think I remove it by mistake when shortening the code the last time, I will just make a rollback edit

Answer (score 1):

**Perl**: <s>144</s> 133

```
$|=@s=(($")x50,map{$_,($")x4}@i=split//,pop);{$n=0;$s[$n]ne$_?last:$n++for@i;splice@s,$n,1;print"\r",@s[0..50];sleep.1;$n!=@i&&redo}
```

In order to get the sleep of <1s though you need to run as:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=sleep scriptname 'string to print'
```

Since I won't declare myself winner I won't argue myself over what counts there or not (but I really can't have Ruby win this ;-) )

Comment: 4 more and it fits on a tweet :D

Comment: 4 characters right here: `s/' '/$"/g` and `s/shift/pop/`

Comment: yeah, I had included those, along with removing the `push` statement. I just hadn't posted it yet.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5.13.2, 115 characters

```
$_=$"x9 .pop=~y/ /\0/r;s/./    $&/g;print(y/\0/ /r=~/(.{50})/,"\r"),select$.,$.,$.,.02while$|=s/ (\S)/$1 /g;print$/
```

- Warning-clean.
- Can be squeezed a bit by reducing the space between characters or the initial whitespace.
- Requires Perl 5.13.2 or newer due to use of `/r`.
- The substitution to NUL to preserve spaces is unambiguous since POSIX argv is not NUL-clean. However, the loop substitution will turn any other whitespace into nothing (eventually).

Credits:

- `$"` as a source of `" "` taken from [ephemient's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/scrolling-marquee/5322#5322), reduction by 1 character.

Comment: I love the `r` flag, best addition to the language since `state`

Answer (score 1):

### R, 319 characters

Following the philosophy of @Blazer example (d is the delay in sec):

```
f=function(x,n=50,d=0.2){
    s=strsplit(x,"")[[1]];i=1;l=length
    while (i<(n+l(s)-1)){
        if(i<=l(s))cat(rep(" ", n-i),s[1:i])
        else if((i<=n)&&(i>l(s)))cat(rep(" ", n-i),s[1:l(s)])
        else cat(paste(s[1:(i-n+1)],collapse=""),s[(i-n+2):l(s)])
        Sys.sleep(d);system("clear");i=i+1
    }
    cat(paste(s[1:l(s)],collapse=""))
}
```

Usage:

```
f("Hello World",n=20,d=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Q,145

Doesn't exactly meet the requirements because the final line removes all the spaces that were in the original input string.

```
{c:2_'((!)(#)a)_'a:((l:3*(#)x)#" "),\(1_(,/)b,'x,'b:" ");{(-1 x;);system"sleep ",($)y}'[-1_c,(l-1)$d(!:)[d]except\(&)(^)d:((!)(#)q)!q:last c;y];}
```

It takes two arguments, input string and scroll speed

```
q){c:2_'((!)(#)a)_'a:((l:3*(#)x)#" "),\(1_(,/)b,'x,'b:" ");{(-1 x;);system"sleep ",($)y}'[-1_c,(l-1)$d(!:)[d]except\(&)(^)d:((!)(#)q)!q:last c;y];}["hello";0.05]
             h
            h
           h
          h  e
         h  e
        h  e
       h  e  l
      h  e  l
     h  e  l
    h  e  l  l
   h  e  l  l
  h  e  l  l
 h  e  l  l  o
h  e  l  l  o
h e  l  l  o
he  l  l  o
he l  l  o
hel  l  o
hel l  o
hell  o
hell o
hello
```

Comment: unfortunately thats an important point. I know that the Perl scripts could get very small without it.

Answer (score 0):

#### PowerShell, 135

Not very golfed and probably a horrible approach, but I'm sick and can't really think ...

```
for($x="`r"+' '*50;$y-ne$x){$y=$x
write-host($x=$x-replace' ([^ ])','$1 ')-n
if(!($t++%5)){$x=$x-replace'.$',"$args"[$i++]}sleep -m 99}
```

Answer (score 0):

### J (116)

```
s(echo@((50#LF)&,)@([[i.@]&2e7)@(50&{.)@;@:(([,~#&' '@])&.>))"1([-=&0@/:@\:@:~:&0)^:(i.>:+/k)k=.50,3#~<:#s=.>2{ARGV
```

Takes the input string on the command line, i.e. `jconsole marquee.ijs 'Hello, world!'`

If it doesn't need to clear the screen, i.e. output like this:

```
H  e  l  l  o
H e  l  l  o
He  l  l  o
He l  l  o
...
```

is allowed, it would be 12 characters shorter.

Explanation:

- `s.=>2{ARGV`: get the string from the command line
- `k.=50,3#~<:#s`: the starting amount of whitespace added before each character, 50 before the first one and 3 before all the others. (gives an array, '50 3 3 3...')
- `([-=&0@/:@\:@~:&0)`: given an array, decrements the first nonzero item in the array
- `^:(i.>:+/k)`: this function applied N times, where N is 0 upto the sum of the amount of added whitespace. (gives a matrix: `50 3 3 3; 49 3 3 3; 48 3 3 3; ... 0 0 0 1; 0 0 0 0)`.
- `"1`: run following function on each row of the matrix
- `;@:(([,~#&' '@])@.>)`: add the given amount of spaces before each character in the string
- `(50&{.)`: take the first 50 characters of the string
- `([[i.@]&2e7)`: a function that generates the list from 0 to 2*10^7, and then throws it away. This takes about a third of a second on my machine, this causes the delay.
- `((50#LF)&,)`: add 50 newlines before the string, to clear the screen
- `echo`: output the string
- `s (...)`: give the string as the left argument to the function

Answer (score 0):

### APL (70)

```
{⎕SM∘←1,⍨1,⍨,/D{⍺,⍨⍵⍴⍕⍬}¨P←⍵-{⍵×~×⍺}\×⍵⊣⎕DL÷8⋄0∨.≠P:∇P}1↓⎕SD,1↓3⍴⍨⍴D←⍞
```

Takes input from the keyboard, the output is in the `⎕SM` window (which would be the terminal if you had a text-based APL I guess). The window size is detected automatically, if you really want it to be 50 change the `1↓⎕SD` to `50`.

Explanation:

- `1↓⎕SD,1↓3⍴⍨⍴D←⍞`: read the string and store in `D`. Generate a vector describing how much whitespace to add before each character, which is the screen width before the first character (`1↓⎕SD`), and 3 before the others (`1↓3⍴⍨⍴D`).
- `⎕DL÷8`: wait 1/8th of a second
- `P←⍵-{⍵×~×⍺}\×⍵`: in the vector in the right argument, subtract 1 from the leftmost nonzero item, and store the new vector in P.
- `,/D{⍺,⍨⍵⍴⍕⍬}¨P`: for each character in D, prefix the amount of whitespace given in P.
- `⎕SM∘←1,⍨1,⍨`: display on the screen, in the leftmost column of the top row
- `0∨.≠P:∇P`: if there is a nonzero element in P, repeat with P.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 129 bytes

```powershell
for($x=' '*52+(($args|% t*y)-join' '*4);$x-match'  '){write-host "`r$(-join($x=$x-replace'(?<!  .*)  ')[0..50])  "-n
sleep -m 99}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY69DoJAEIR7nmI1J3dgjhCjhVFjYaGlnYUxkejyYw6W7GFU0GdH0G4y881kSnog2xSNaUUMK2jamFiJ50qC9GeTsVIi4sS@R1D5L0/fKCv6ZOotxFPnUXVJJYD0mgdnFeqUbAXDMwv1I/udDmMsTXRBqdbLAUDge33jGAbBLDx1eqgLxxrEEnQO8/mn/TiO252Ru@4VwYHYXOXf2TMlHOV5ViSwv9e1QQsubOiKsCUTy/YL)

This script does not remove spaces from the arguments in contrast to [Joey's script](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5668/80745).

`TIO` does not display the output correctly. With Powershell console, you get the scrolling marqueeline.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 42 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ð¶:S3úJ46ú[D50£¶ð:D?IQ#ðõ.;“…¢('\r')“.eт.W
```

[Try it online (without the sleep).](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8IZD26yCjQ/v8jIxO7wr2sXU4NDiQ9sOb7BysfcMVD684fBWPetHDXMeNSw7tEhDPaZIXRPI0wNq9EjNyclXCM8vykkBAA) NOTE: I don't have 05AB1E installed locally, so I'm not 100% sure if the `\r` trick works (in theory it should work, however). In TIO the `\r` are interpret as newlines instead. Also, the TIO uses the legacy version, because `.e` is disabled in the new TIO version (program is the same in both the legacy and new version of 05AB1E, though).

**Explanation:**

```python
ð¶:            # Replace all spaces in the (implicit) input-string with newlines
   S           # Split the string to a list of characters
    3ú         # Pad each character with 3 leading spaces
      J        # Join the characters together again
       46ú     # And pad the entire string with an additional 46 leading spaces
[              # Now start an infinite loop:
 D             #  Duplicate the string
  50£          #  And leave only the first 50 characters of this copy as substring
     ¶ð:       #  Replace the newlines back to spaces
        D?     #  Duplicate the string, and print it without trailing newline
 IQ            #  If the current string is equal to the input:
   #           #   Stop the infinite loop
 ðõ.;          #  Replace the first space with an empty string to remove it
 “…¢('\r')“    #  Push dictionary string "print('\r')"
           .e  #  Evaluate it as Python code
 т.W           #  Sleep for 100 ms
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `“…¢('\r')“` is `"print('\r')"`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 139 bytes

```
import os;P='\n'
def f(x,w):
 v=k=P*w+P.join(x);o=str.replace
 while v!=x:os.system('sleep 1;clear');k=o(k,P,'',1);v=o(k,P,' ');print v[:w]
```

Has to call `f('Hello World', 50)` to start.