# Animate the text in your terminal

Tags: code-golf, string, hello-world, animation

### Animate the text in your terminal

**The goal**

The goal is to "animate" the string "Hello world" in your output so that each character gets capitalised after each other.

Your program can exit after each letter has been capitalised.

For example;

```
# Iteration 1
Hello world

# Iteration 2
hEllo world

# Iteration 3
heLlo world

# Iteration 4
helLo world

# Iteration 5
hellO world

# Iteration 6 (note: it should capitilize the space char (ie: a break between iteration 5 and iteration 7)
hello world

# Iteration 7
hello World

# Iteration 8
hello wOrld

# Iteration 9
hello woRld

# Iteration 10
hello worLd

# Iteration 11
hello worlD
```

It should only animate the string once and between each state there should be a 1 second delay.

**Input**

No input is required, but "Hello world" must be the string that is "animated".

**Output**

The string "Hello world" must be animated. The output must be as 1 line to create a sort of wave animation. An empty trailing new line is allowed. Example gif;

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/be12b693063b463540c5bf1f03d2454a.gif]

<sup>I saw this on a metasploit youtube video and thought the effect was pretty cool, which is where I recorded the gif from, so it's a little laggy, but I hope it illustrates the output fine</sup>

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest byte-count will be deemed the winner.

<sup>[Sandbox Link](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11486/38505)</sup>

Comment: Can it exit and stop with an error?

Comment: @StewieGriffin as long as the animation is viewable, sure.

Comment: I don't think the 1 second delay adds to the challenge. We've had a bunch like that and each time it seems like the same boilerplate is added.

Comment: @xnor Do you mean the duration of the delay being 1 second explicitly, or do you mean any delay at all? Latter wouldn't make any sense since it's an animation after all..

Comment: @Metoniem Any fixed-time delay.

Comment: Oh, in that case I agree for sure. Writing 1000 instead of 1 costs me 3 bytes already >:( @xnor

Comment: @ʰᵈˑAre additional leading iterations allowed?

Comment: @Metoniem No, only the ones described in the goal. Unless I've misunderstood. Each letter must be capitalised once from left to right once only, starting with "H" in "hello" and ending with "D" in "world"

Comment: @ʰᵈˑYou understood! Okay then, thanks.

Comment: For a better view of this effect as seen when starting the Metasploit Framework: [Metasploit For Beginners - #1 @~5:50](https://youtu.be/8lR27r8Y_ik?t=5m50s)

Answer (score 34):

## Vim 26 bytes

```
ihello world<ESC>qq~gsul@qq0@q
```

Explanation (no .gif yet):

First, we must enter the 'hello world' text. This is pretty straightforward. It's just:

```
ihello world<ESC>
```

At this point, the cursor is on the 'd' in 'world'. Next:

```
qq              " Start recording into register 'q'
  ~             " Swap the case of the character underneath the cursor, and move the cursor to the right
   gs           " Sleep for one second
     u          " Undo the last change (of swapping case).
      l         " Move one character to the right (Get it? 'l' == 'Right' because vim is intuitive!)
                " This will cause the error to break on the last character of the input.
       @q       " Call register 'q'
         q      " Stop recording
          0     " Move to the first character
           @q   " Call the recursive macro
```

There are also two other 26 byte versions I found:

```
ihello world<ESC>qq~gsulq011@q
ihello world<ESC>011@='~gsul'<cr>
```

Comment: Man that's cool! Here's the output: https://i.gyazo.com/52d0b9268446aed36ce7eb641c40ff6c.gif (half of it anyway, Gyazo stopped recording)

Comment: I don't think `~`  breaks the [loop](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@394U93hTf//Z6Tm5OQrlOcX5aQAAA). I believe it's the `l` that does the hard work

Comment: @KritixiLithos Ah, after testing it, it seems you're right. Good point, I'll edit that out

Comment: Can confirm -- This works.

Answer (score 15):

## Python 2, <s>98</s> <s>94</s> 90 bytes

```
for x in range(11):s='hello world';print'\r'+s[:x]+s[x:].capitalize(),;[1for y in' '*8**8]
```

<s>-9</s> -4 bytes thanks to @ElPedro
-4 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan and @Rod

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, nice first post c:

Comment: Nice post! This seems to have a capital "H" and "W" at the same time though https://repl.it/Fhii - It seems to not lowercase the "H"

Comment: About the printing problem, you can pass [`-u` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) and [use `print"\t"+s[:x]+s[x:].title(),;` (note the trailing comma)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419389/how-to-overwrite-the-previous-print-to-stdout-in-python). And this won't change your byte count (because the argument would add +2 bytes)

Comment: Isn't each flag only one byte? Or am I confusing two different topics? @Rod

Comment: @Timtech hmm, I couldn't find any meta topic about, but other answers count as 2

Comment: @Rod Strange I can't either, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @Rod The flag would count as one byte because an acceptable invocation for Python is `python -c 'code here'`. With the flag, the invocation would be `python -uc 'code here'`, which is one byte different.

Comment: `print"\r"+s[:x]+s[x:].capitalize(),;` doesn't require an extra flag

Comment: @JMat [Technically? No. In practice? Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793296/python-sleep-inhibit-print-with-comma)

Comment: [Pretty much your version, but 95 bytes and clears the screen](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcxBCoAgFAXAvadwV1EEtrQ8SbWI@tCDV4oJQpc3mgNMwRV8TDrhEkVXLfEU0uvsI49KwRmVT1A0JjPYEHEnzdlibTnDrv2@BaSNeKVuuhGtM@Nf9Q9FQm2aUj4) (I tested with 2.7.8 on Windows 7-64). Try It Online does not give the animation, just the line by line result.

Comment: @JonathanAllan `i=-11` with `while i:` also works (to save 1 byte)

Comment: @Rod, that it does.

Comment: You can get it down to 85 by replacing sleep with a "time-wasting" loop `[1for y in' '*8**8]` and doing away with the import. `8**8` gives a delay of approximately one second on my machine but will vary depending on hardware. Doesn't actually work on [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcxBCoAgEADAr@xt0yLwJkovMQ9BVoJorEL2erPLHKcdiaCCj0BbPN0gBFN5wcuFkOBJFHbUN/lYcCUcs1HVdquyc/EluIFN2oj/ePuBgFxyLm1rHw "Python 2 – TIO Nexus") as it just dumps the whole list at the end but the code is there for reference.

Comment: My mistake. Actually 90 because `.title()` will always capitalize the `w` after the space. Updated with `capitalize()` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcxBCoAgEADAr@xt1SLwJkYvKQ9SVoJobELW560uc5y6JoICPgLZuDkmJdfngLsLIcGVKCzYH@RjxomwOUddzGfRppvt4bMN/nGMt/0o/@j@IgQUSghlan0B "Python 2 – TIO Nexus"). Sorry about that.

Comment: @ElPedro thanks for pointing this out, already corrected this mistake previously, so forgot to check again.

Answer (score 12):

## Commodore 64, <strike>168</strike> <strike>162</strike> <strike>137</strike> 133 BASIC (and tokenized) bytes used

```
 0s=1024:?"{control+n}{clear home}hello world":fOi=.to1:fOj=.to11:x=pE(s+j):pokes+j,x+64
 1x=pE(1023+j):pO1023+j,abs(x-64):pO1029,32:pO1035,32:fOz=.to99:i=.:nEz,j,i
```

You will need to use BASIC keyword abbreviations to enter this into a real C64 or emulator (or enter the program into a Commodore 128 and load it back in C64 mode, although this should work on the 128 as well). The `{control+n}` will only work/display after the opening quote. It is shorthand for `chr$(14)` and therefore saves some bytes and switches the character set to *business mode* or upper/lower case characters.

I have added in some abbreviations for you so you. The `{clear home}` character is made by pressing `Shift` and the `CLR/HOME` key after the opening quotation mark.

For illustrative purposes the unobfustcated listing may be entered as follows:

```
 0 let s=1024
 1 print chr$(14); chr$(147); "hello world"
 2 for i=0 to 1
 3  for j=0 to 11
 4   let x=peek(s + j)
 5   poke s + j, x + 64
 6   let x=peek(1023 + j)
 7   poke 1023 + j, abs(x - 64)
 8   poke 1029, 32
 9   poke 1035, 32
10   for z=0 to 99
11    let i=0
12   next z
13  next j
14 next i
```

It works by switching the PETSCII charset into business mode (upper/lower case), and writing the hello world string to the top line of the screen which is located at memory location $0400, it will then take the value at each location for the next 11 bytes from there and increase each value by 64 (the upper case equivalent). If the j counter is > 0, it calls a routine at line 2 to decrease the previous memory location by 64 again.

Line 3 is a pause, it also writes a space to to location $0405 and $040b, which is a bug fix (which could probably be removed to save some bytes).

[image: Commodore C64 animated hello world]

Comment: I should add that `fori=0to1step0` ... `nexti` is essentially creating an infinite (goto-less) loop, kind of like `while(true){...}` in more modern languages.

Comment: Why don't you just use a goto instead of an infinite loop? Even with the 2 newlines that would have to be added, it would still save bytes. Also RAM bytes isn't the same as the number of bytes in your code.

Comment: Because `GO TO` is banned, right ;-) One may easily work out the listing by itself by `CLR` before working out the remain free bytes with the broken `FRE(0)` function

Comment: oh sorry about that

Answer (score 11):

## C#, <s>230</s> <s>215</s> <s>193</s> <s>161</s> <s>135</s> <s>134</s> 130 bytes

It's C# so it's long right! :-( But after some help and searching, I (and others, really) managed to remove exactly 100 bytes already.

### Golfed

```
()=>{for(int i=1;;){var b="\rhello world".ToCharArray();b[i++]-=' ';System.Console.Write(b);System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);}}
```

### Ungolfed

```
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 1;;)
        {
            var b = "\rhello world".ToCharArray();
            b[i++] -= ' ';
            System.Console.Write(b);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Animation with 1 second delay]
Although it looks alot better when looping and faster..

#### Updates

- Lost 15 bytes by using carriage return instead of `Clear()` which also allowed me to replace a using with `System.Console`somewhere inline.
- Replaced program with lambda saving 23 bytes thanks to **@devRicher**
- It became kind of a collaboration with **@devRicher** at this point, thanks to some of his suggestions I managed to lose another 32 bytes!
- Thanks to 2 really smart and interesting suggestions by **@Kratz** I managed to replace `new string(b)` with `b` and `b[i]=char.ToUpper(b[i])` with `b[i]-=' '`, saving me another 26 bytes!
- 1 byte less by moving `i++` thanks to **@Snowfire**
- 4 bytes less by moving carriage return to the beginning of the string and removing `i<11` from my `for` loop

Comment: Change `class P{static void Main(){ ... }}` to `()=>{ ... }` to snip off a few bytes. PPCG accepts functions as answers, so a lambda works fine.

Comment: @devRicher Ah I see, I never used lambas before, but that seems like a cool improvement. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know how to use them (or don't want to), its still fine for a simple `void g(){ ... }`.

Comment: You can access strings with array indices (`char g = string j[x]`), to save around 50 bytes: `()=>{var s="Hello world";for(int i=1;i<11;i++){string h = s;h[i]=char.ToUpper(s[i]);System.Console.Write(h+"\r");System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);}}`

Comment: @devRicher I know you can access them using indices, but unfortunately they're readonly, so I think that might not work here. Correct me if I'm wrong though!

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I got that wrong. I'll look for more stuff to golf. *i love c# answers*

Comment: How about `()=>{var s="Hello world\r".ToCharArray();for(int i=1;i<11;i++){var b=s;b[i]=char.ToUpper(s[i]);System.Console.Write(new string(b));System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);}}`? Not sure if `Hello World\r` yields right results, but I changed up other parts of it too.

Comment: @devRicher This turns them all uppercase and not lowercase anymore. Probably because `b` is just a pointer to `s`, also if we would actually copy the array and use this, I think the "H" in `Hello world` will stay capitalized which isn't supposed to happen. The idea behind it is nice, though!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53556/discussion-between-metoniem-and-devricher).

Comment: Instead of `Char.ToUpper`, you can do `s[i]-=' ';` Also, write will take an array of char, no need to make a new string, just `Write(s)`.

Comment: @Kratz that sounds interesting. Let me try that real quick!

Comment: @Kratz Woah, the `-=' '` is very smart. Added both to my answer, thanks!

Comment: You can save another byte by removing the incrementation from the for clause and putting it in the array access like `b[i++]-=' '`.
That would come in handy, because then you could also remove the condition in the for loop and just write `for(int i=0;;)`.
OP pointed out in the comments, that the program may exit with an error, so you can allow an IndexOutOfRangeException

Comment: @Snowfire Nice find! Thanks (edit: See you edited your comment, you're right, removing the condition from the `for` loop will work, thanks again!)

Comment: Actually @Snowfire I'm afraid I will have to rollback the removal of that condition. I forgot it'll then reach `\r` too, and `'\r'-' '` becomes `?` which is then printed :-(

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure about that either, but it isn't really specified, whether that is allowed or not.

Comment: @Snowfire True.. I asked in a comment just now. i'll leave it out of my answer until I know for sure.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not possible without casting to `int` I think.

Comment: I'm wondering if you can use the exact carriage return character (`0x0d`) instead of `\r` in your code to save 1 more byte.

Answer (score 11):

## Powershell, <s>126</s> <s>119</s> <s>107</s> 104 Bytes

```
'Hello world';$s='hello world';1..10|%{sleep 1;cls;-join($s[0..($_-1)]+[char]($s[$_]-32)+$s[++$_..11])}
```

[image]

Revisions (there will likely be many):

Change `$s.Length` to const <s>`10`</s> 11

Restructured string builder, removed 1 join statement and used `++$s` instead of `($s+1)`, to save some bytes thanks to [@AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42963/admborkbork)

AdmBorkBork points out just using the string twice is actually shorter than encapsulating and then `.ToLower()`'ing it - which says a lot about how verbose powershell is, -3!

---

basically loop through the length of the string, form an array of three parts, the pre-capitcal, capital, and post-capital, take 32 away from the middle letter, then convert back to a char to get upper case, luckily this doesn't turn space into a visible character either, I hope this is acceptable?

Comment: You can save three more bytes off the front by simply printing the string rather than saving it into `$s` and `.ToLower()`ing it. -- `'Hello world';$s='hello world';`

Comment: [102 bytes inline-ing $s](https://tio.run/##TYyxCoAgFAD3vqLBUBGlV2O09w8iEiVYPDJ0aKi@3Ryb7objznC5mLxDzJlOBaG@QsSVVqAUtE9zJ3TurGFYMA1yD9vBGEkj9b@W61YpRqwEboRe/BxNaTSxRvYdF0WFILb8wPA35w8 "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 9):

### [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) assembly, 50 DECLEs = 63 bytes

This code is intended to be run on an [Intellivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellivision).

A CP-1610 opcode is encoded with a 10-bit value, known as a 'DECLE'. This program is 50 DECLEs long, starting at $4800 and ending at $4831.

```
                                  ROMW  10          ; use 10-bit ROM
                                  ORG   $4800       ; start program at address $4800

                          main    PROC
4800 0002                         EIS               ; enable interrupts (to enable display)

4801 0001                         SDBD              ; load pointer to string in R4
4802 02BC 0026 0048               MVII  #@@str, R4

4805 02A2                         MVI@  R4,     R2  ; R2 = length of string
4806 0091                         MOVR  R2,     R1  ; R1 = uppercase counter

4807 02BD 0214            @@loop  MVII  #$214,  R5  ; R5 = video memory pointer
4809 0093                         MOVR  R2,     R3  ; R3 = character counter

480A 02A0                 @@next  MVI@  R4,     R0  ; R0 = next character
480B 0338 0020                    SUBI  #32,    R0  ; minus 32 -> character #
480D 004C                         SLL   R0,     2   ; multiply by 8 to get the
480E 0048                         SLL   R0          ; correct GROM card
480F 03F8 0007                    XORI  #7,     R0  ; add 7 (for white)

4811 014B                         CMPR  R1,     R3  ; uppercase? ...
4812 020C 0002                    BNEQ  @@draw

4814 0338 0100                    SUBI  #256,   R0  ; ... yes: sub 32*8

4816 0268                 @@draw  MVO@  R0,     R5  ; draw character
4817 0013                         DECR  R3          ; decrement character counter
4818 022C 000F                    BNEQ  @@next      ; process next character or stop

481A 0001                         SDBD              ; R0 = spin counter to wait ~1 second
481B 02B8 0038 00D3               MVII  #$D338, R0  ;    = 54072 = 13518 * 60 / 15
                                                    ; (assuming 13518 cycles per frame)

481E 0010                 @@spin  DECR  R0          ; 6 cycles
481F 022C 0002                    BNEQ  @@spin      ; 9 cycles
                                                    ; -> 15 cycles per iteration

4821 0114                         SUBR  R2,     R4  ; reset pointer to beginning of string
4822 0011                         DECR  R1          ; decrement uppercase counter
4823 022C 001D                    BNEQ  @@loop      ; process next iteration or stop

4825 0017                         DECR  PC          ; infinite loop

4826 000B 0068 0065 006C  @@str   STRING 11, "hello world"
482A 006C 006F 0020 0077
482E 006F 0072 006C 0064
                                  ENDP
```

#### Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 30 bytes

```
11:"10&Xx'hello world't@)Xk@(D
```

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=11%3A%2210%26Xx%27hello+world%27t%40%29Xk%40%28D&inputs=&version=19.7.4)

```
11:              % Push [1 2 ... 11]
  "              % For each k in [1 2 ... 11]
  10&Xx          %   Pause for 10 tenths of a second and clear screen
  'hello world'  %   Push this string
  t              %   Duplicate
  @)             %   Get the k-th character from the duplicated string
  Xk             %   Convert to uppercase
  @(             %   Write into the k-th position of the string
  D              %   Display
                 % Implicit end
```

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>76</s> <s>74</s> 71 bytes

Thank you @hd for the delay being a full second and no fraction thereof!
Thanks @user63956 for 2 bytes and @aross for 3 bytes.

```php
for(;$c=($s="hello world")[$i];sleep(print"$s\r"))$s[$i++]=ucfirst($c);
```

Run with `-nr`.

Comment: You can save 2 bytes with `sleep(print"$s\r")`.

Comment: Save 3 bytes with [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>97</s> <s>withdrawn</s> 106 bytes

with escaped characters counted as 1 byte

```c
char*a="HELLO\0WORLD\xED";b,c;m(){for(b=0;b<156;putchar(a[c]+32*(b/12^c||c==5)))(c=b++%12)||fflush(sleep(1));}
```

Note: I have <s>commented out the time delay on</s> unlinked TIO because it waits for completion before displaying the output, it also doesn't seem to recognize carriage returns and puts new lines. Also, if you're on Windows, sleep is in milliseconds instead of seconds, so `sleep(1)` should become `sleep(1000)`.

<s>Note 2: I've withdrawn this entry for the moment until the output bugs have been ironed out.</s>

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't output anything on my machine

Comment: If you're on windows you will have to change the delay, it will also finish on a carriage return so you may want to change 130 to 129 so it avoids printing it during the last iteration.

Comment: For me this program does not end at all, and it doesn't output anything. I had to manually `^C` it to stop it . (also I'm on mac)

Comment: I believe it's a print buffer issue, I'll withdraw my entry for now.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>141 139</s> 131 bytes

*Saved 8B thanks to Apsillers*

```
_=>a=setInterval("b=[...`hello world`],c.clear(b[d]=b[d].toUpperCase(++d>10&&clearInterval(a))),c.log(b.join``)",1e3,c=console,d=0)
```

## Explanation

This creates a function with no arguments, which splits the string `hello world` into an array of characters and capitalises the `d+1`<sup>th</sup> character. `d` is a counter that starts as `0` and is increased every time.

## Usage

```
f=_=>a=setInterval("b=[...`hello world`],c.clear(b[d]=b[d].toUpperCase(++d>10&&clearInterval(a))),c.log(b.join``)",1e3,c=console,d=0)
f()
```

Comment: Clever, I'll update it.

Comment: Also, I don't see any reason to make this a function, since it takes no input -- just run the code, right?

Comment: The question says it's supposed to be a program, but in that case you can also submit a function. Code snippets are generally not allowed.

Comment: This is nice, gg!

Comment: Can you distinguish between your understanding of a disallowed "code snippet" versus an allowed "program" in this case? If you just remove the leading `_=>` you *do* have a complete program (e.g., if you stuck it in a file, Node.js would run successfully it to completion). My understanding of the prohibition against "code snippets" is against writing code that implicitly accepts some input as a variable, like "if we assume `i` already has the input, we can do..." which is not happening here, since there explicitly is no input.

Answer (score 4):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/), 22 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

```
”<8@\|DḶ|\6þıHḶƥɲSḍsɲS
```

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%E2%80%9D%3C8%40%5C%7CD%E1%B8%B6%7C%5C6%C3%BE%C4%B1H%E1%B8%B6%C6%A5%C9%B2S%E1%B8%8Ds%C9%B2S&input=&run=true)

---

## How it works

```
”<8@\|DḶ|\6þ           # Displays the string "hello¤world".
”<8@\|DḶ|\6            # Decompresses to the array ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "¤", "w", "o", "r", "l", "d"] and pushes it on top of the stack.
           þ           # Pushes a copy of the array to the screen which since is an array is done by reference.

            ı          # Makes the array on the top of the stack the new stack.

             HḶƥɲSḍsɲS # Loops eleven times creating the animation.
             H         # Pushes the string "H" on to the top of the stack.
              Ḷ        # Consumes the "H" that gets evaluated as a base 98 number which comes out to eleven.
               ƥ       # Move the stack pointer up one.
                ɲS     # Switch the case of the top of the stack which will show up on the screen because the array is done by reference.
                  ḍs   # Delay for one second.
                    ɲS # Switch the case back.
                       # Implicit end of the loop.
```

---

The snippet uses a **25 byte** version that loops continuously.

```html
<div id="noodel" cols="10" rows="2" code="”<8@\|DḶ|\6þıḷʠ*HḶƥɲSḍsɲS" input=""/>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/release/noodel-2.5.js"></script>
<script src="https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/ppcg.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, <s>99</s> 98 bytes

```
x=hello\ world
for((;n<11;)){
echo -en "\r${x:0:n}"`tr a-z A-Z<<<"${x:n:1}"`"${x:n+++1}"
sleep 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), <s>65</s> 61 bytes

```perl6
for 3..12 ->\i{sleep say "\echello world".&{S:nth(i)/./{$/.uc}/}}
```

```perl6
(sleep say S:nth(3+$++)/./{$/.uc}/with "\echello world")xx 11
```

GIF: [image]

#### How it works

The ANSI escape sequence `\ec` clears the screen.
Each iteration, the `i`'th character of the hard-coded string is substituted by its upper-case version.
The `say` function always returns `True`, which is passed on to the sleep function which interprets it as `1` second.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <s>82</s> 81 bytes

```
12.times{|a|$><<?^H*11;'Hello world'.chars{|y|$><<((0!=a-=1)?y:y.upcase)};sleep 1}
```

^H is ascii 8 (backspace), and is only 1 byte.

Answer (score 3):

## C, 87 bytes

```
m(){char*f,a[]="\rhello world";for(f=a;*++f;*f&=95,printf(a),*f|=32,fflush(sleep(1)));}
```

Compiles and runs on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>106</s> 103 bytes

```r
x=el(strsplit("hello world",""))
for(i in 1:11){y=x;y[i]=toupper(y[i]);cat('\f',y,sep='');Sys.sleep(1)}
```

Just a simple loop, clearing the console with `cat('\f')` seems somewhat system-dependent but I am not aware of a better way.

Comment: I tried outgolfing this using `utf8ToInt`. This did not work, the space needs to be handled as a special case. In the process I discovered that `cat("\014")` seemed to work better then work where `cat("\f")` did not.[but not on TIO](https://tio.run/##BcFBCgIxDADAu68ouTSBKBY8qfuKPa4eRCMGgg1NRUR8e51pY8QkhtFbuGlHeIhZTe/a7AYMQLS614aa9JnKvhT6Xi8d82lbdplhOa4Bg5V7fblLw1j0TMQhPuVMh/kTmzARx0K/Mf4)

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>130</s> <s>128</s> <s>123</s> <s>110</s> 108 bytes

```
Dynamic@o
s="hello world";i=1;t=StringTake;Do[o=t[s,{1,i-1}]<>Capitalize@t[s,{i}]<>t[s,{++i,11}];Pause@1,11]
```

Explanation: From `i=1` to 11, print from the 1st to the (i-1)th character of "hello world", capitalise `"hello world"[i]`, then print the rest of the string, incrementing `i` at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

## Java <s>215</s> <s>212</s> <s>204</s> 203 bytes

```
interface A{static void main(String z[])throws Exception{for(int i=0;i<10;i++){char[]b="helloworld".toCharArray();b[i]=Character.toUpperCase(b[i]);System.out.println(new String(b));Thread.sleep(1000);}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
 interface A {
 static void main(String z[]) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        char[] b = "helloworld".toCharArray();
        b[i] = Character.toUpperCase(b[i]);
        System.out.println(new String(b));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `interface A` (with a space)? Plus you can remove the space between `,` and `Character.toUpperCase`.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Kudos to @NoOneIsHere for the 3 points

Comment: Thanks @DJMcMayhem, Always liked reading through the challenges and finally got to answer one!

Answer (score 2):

## C, 122 bytes

```c
i;f(){char s[]="Hello world\r";for(i=0;i<11;i++){s[i]=toupper(s[i]);s[i-1]=tolower(s[i-1]);printf(s);fflush(0);sleep(1);}}
```

Shorter than C# :D

Comment: Also for the last frame to be visible, you have to do `i<11` instead of `i<10` in your for-loop

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 75 bytes

```
sleep print"\33c".("hello world"=~s/(.{$_})(.)(.*)/$1\U$2\E$3\n/r)for 0..10
```

Uses the ANSI code <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to clear the console and move the cursor to the top left at every iteration, but still needs `\n` at the end of the replace string to avoid having the whole animation lost in the line buffer.

A successful call to `print` returns a value of 1, which can be passed directly to `sleep`.

Comment: You can use `$\`` and `$'` to save a few bytes on that `(.{$_})(.)(.*)` (it won't work in a terminal, but that's not a problem). It requires modifying a little bit the rest of your code though: `"hello world"=~s/./sleep print"\33c$\`\U$&\E$'\n"/ger`. (I wrote almost this exact code, then when looking if anyone had posted a perl answer yet, I found yours). And a little detail about the bytecount : you can use a litteral newline to save a byte, and maybe some kind of litteral `\33c` (not too sure about that last one though).

Answer (score 2):

### C <s>120</s> <s>110</s> <s>104</s> 96 bytes

```
f(){char *j,s[]="\rhello world";for(j=s;*++j;*j-=32,printf(s),*j+=32,fflush(0),sleep(‌​1));}
```

Ungolfed version

```
void f()
{
  char *j;
  char s[]="hello world";
  j=s; 

   for (;*j;j++)
   {
      *j-=32;  
       printf(s); // print the string and right after change the same char to lower case
       *j+=32;
      fflush(0);
      sleep(1);
   }

}
```

@Pakk Thanks for saving some bytes, great idea. :)

@Pakk @KarlNapf Thanks guys for your inputs.

can still be shortened!? :)

Comment: Use `-=` and `+=`. Also, a pointer variable might save the `[]` but i am not sure.

Comment: The `j` should be outside the function

Comment: @KarlNapf You're obviously right about the `+=` and `-=` , completely forgot. Updated. :)

Comment: @KritixiLithos Thanks for pointing out, Updated!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think instead of `if(j)s[j-1]+=32` you can do `j&&s[j-1]+=32` (haven't tested it though)

Comment: char *j;f(){char s[]="hello world";for(j=s;*j;j++){*j-=32;printf("\r%s",s);*j+=32;fflush(0);sleep(1);}}  (103 chars)

Comment: Idea behind previous comment: Make it lowercase again after the printf, then you don't have to check if j-1 exists. And use pointers to save some characters.

Comment: @KritixiLithos `j&&s[j-1]+=32` does not work. compilaton error

Comment: @Pakk Updated, Thanks for the idea. :)

Comment: `char *j,s[]="hello world";` to save a few more chars.

Comment: And my final idea: define s as `"\rhello world";`, add a `++j` to skip the `\r`, then you can print with `printf(s);`, which should save a few bytes. Not tested.

Comment: `f(){char*j,s[]="\rhello world";for(j=s;*++j;*j-=32,printf(s),*j+=32,fflush(0),sleep(1));}` 89 bytes.

Comment: @KarlNapf you can shorten it to `fflush(sleep(1))`

Comment: @KarlNapf, It fails at the 5'th iteration where ' ' - 32 truncates the string into 'hello\0'

Answer (score 2):

## Pascal, <s>187</s> 152 bytes

Not exactly the most efficient or the shortest, but works quite well!

```
uses crt,sysutils;label R;const X:Word=1;P='hello world';begin
R:clrscr;write(P);gotoxy(X,1);write(upcase(P[X]));sleep(999);X:=X*Ord(X<11)+1;goto R
end.
```

Tested and works on Free Pascal Compiler 2.6+.

Thanks to [@manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) for saving **35** bytes!

---

I've used http://www.onlinecompiler.net/pascal to compile the file and run it on Windows.
Haven't seen any problem with it, so far.

Comment: An `UpCase` function exists since the old Turbo times. (There it handled only `Char`, but in Free Pascal also handles strings.)

Comment: A couple of minor tweaks: is enough to declare X `Word` (or `Byte`); make P a `const` so it infers type from initialization value; while there, make X an initialized constant to get rid of separate `var` keyword (this one may not work in all Pascal variants, but certainly does in Free Pascal); use `ClrScr` to jump to top left corner; replace that `if` with a single expression: `X:=X*Ord(X<11)+1`. http://pastebin.com/FfaixkES

Comment: I really didn't knew that `const X:Word=1;P='hello world';` and that `const X:Word=1;P='hello world';` were possible. I learned Pascal on Turbo Pascal 7, which may not be compatible with that. And completely forgot about `upcase`. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, <s>90</s> 71 bytes

```
FOR I=0TO 10CLS?"hello world
LOCATE I,0?CHR$(CHKCHR(I,0)-32)WAIT 60NEXT
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
”Æ⁹Œu⁸¦ȮœS
“½,⁻⁸3»Jç€
```

This is a niladic link/function that prints to STDOUT. It does not work as a full program.

The code can't be tested on TIO; it uses control characters and TIO has no terminal emulator (yet).

#### How it works

```
“½,⁻⁸3»Jç€  Niladic link. No arguments.

“½,⁻⁸3»     Index into Jelly's dictionary to yield "hello world".
       J    Indices; yield [1, ..., 11].
        ç€  Apply the helper link to each index, with right arg. "hello world".


”Æ⁹Œu⁸¦ȮœS  Dyadic helper link. Left argument: i. Right argument: "hello world"

”Æ          Set the return value to '\r'.
  ⁹         Set the return value to "hello world". Implicitly prints '\r'.
   Œu⁸¦     Uppercase the i-th letter.
       Ȯ    Print.
        œS  Sleep "hello world" seconds. (Strings are cast to Boolean.)
```

Comment: `(Strings are cast to Boolean.)` That's devious!

Answer (score 2):

## C, 122 bytes

As an exercise, I wrote this to provide a more optimal output format than some of the other answers. Also it means the cursor sits after the most recently capitalized letter during the pauses.

```
main(){
    char*p=".Hello world\rH";
    write(1,p+1,13);
    do{
        sleep(1);
        *p=8;
        p[1]|=32;
        p[2]^=(p[2]>32)*32;
        write(1,p++,3);
    }while(p[4]);
}
```

(Newlines and indentations cosmetic and not part of byte count)

Now, some readers may note that this requires some massaging to get to run on modern machines (the magic incantation is `-static -Wl,-N`), but this is how real implementations of C used to behave, so I think it is valid. It also assumes the character set is ASCII, and it does not print a trailing newline.

Bonus: For an EBCDIC version, you can replace `8` with `22` and `64` with `32`, and switch the logic for `p[1]` and `p[2]`. To test on a non-EBCDIC system, you can compile with `-funsigned-char -fexec-charset=cp037`.

Output is 43 bytes: `Hello world«H‹hE‹eL‹lL‹lO‹o ‹ W‹wO‹oR‹rL‹lD`

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 92 bytes

```scala
val h="hello world"
0 to 10 map{i=>print("\b"*99+h.updated(i,h(i)toUpper))
Thread sleep 999}
```

### Ungolfed

```scala
val h="hello world"    //declare a variable h with the string "hello world"
0 to 10                //create a range from 0 to 10
map { i=>              //loop with index i
  print(                 //print
    "\b" * 99              //99 backspace chars
    + h.updated(           //and h with
      i,                     //the i-th char
      h(i).toUpper           //replaced with the i-th char in uppercase
    )     
  )
  Thread sleep 999       //sleep 999 ms
}
```

Comment: +1 for `h(i)toUpper`

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 116 bytes

```clj
(doseq[i(range 11)](Thread/sleep 1000)(print"\r"(apply str(update(vec"hello world")i #(char(-(int %) 32)))))(flush))
```

Basically a for-loop that goes over the indices of each character, updating each character in turn.

```clj
(defn -main []
  (doseq [i (range 11)] ; For the index of each character...
    (Thread/sleep 1000)
    (print "\r" ; Clear old line
           (apply str ; Turn the vector back into a string
             (update ; Update the char at index i
               (vec "hello world") ; Turn the string into a vector so it's updatable
               i ; Index to update
               #(char (- (int %) 32))))) ; Subtract 32 from the character to make uppercase
    (flush)))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, 184 bytes

```
@echo off
for %%h in (Hello hEllo heLlo helLo hellO hello)do call:c %%h world
for %%w in (World wOrld woRld worLd worlD)do call:c hello %%w
exit/b
:c
timeout/t>nul 1
cls
echo %*
```

Curiously the command line for `timeout/t>nul 1` gets corrupted if there is no trailing newline, so I can't put it at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, <s>220</s> <s>189</s> 179 bytes

Solution without using strings and `capitalize()`, byte count as is:

```
import time,sys
from numpy import *
F=fromstring("\rhello world",int8)
for i in range(1,12):
    time.sleep(1)
    F[i]-=32
    savetxt(sys.stdout,F,fmt="%c",newline="")
    F[i]+=32
```

And a bit longer variant (191 chars) without case resetting:

```
import time,sys
from numpy import *
a=arange(11)
F=tile(fromstring("\rhello world",int8),(11,1))
F[a,a+1]-=32
for i in a:
    time.sleep(1)
    savetxt(sys.stdout,F[i],fmt="%c",newline="")
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  It looks like you have done extra whitespace. Particularly around your equal signs

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 108 bytes

First time, first year student. It's no eagle but I'm at least a little proud.

```
12.times{|i|sleep(0.1); puts "\e[H\e[2J", "hello world".sub(/(?<=.{#{Regexp.quote(i.to_s)}})./, &:upcase);}
```

Answer (score 2):

### C++, <strike>88</strike> 125 Bytes

```
#include<iostream>#include<unistd.h>
int main(){for(int c;++c<12;){char a[]="\rhello world";a[c]-=32;std::cout<<a;sleep(1);}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   for (int c;++c<12;)
   {
      char a[] = "\rhello world";
      a[c]-=32;
      std::cout << a;
      sleep(1);
   }
}
```

Compiled with TDM-GCC on a Windows 10 machine with Dev-C++.

Edit: I forgot the includes in my first version.

Comment: Hey, you're the guy that helped me with my C# answer! Your C++ approach made me realise I _can_ actually remove that condition from my `for` loop by moving the carriage return to the beginning of the string.. I'll help you too: Doing `for(int c=1;;c++)` will save you 1 byte.

Comment: Also like you suggested in my C# answer, in combination with my last comment you could then do `for(int c=1;;)` and then `a[c++]-=32;` to save another byte.

Comment: But even with the carriage return in the beginning, it still prints a character (Ó in my case) to the output after hello world even though I'm not really sure why...

Comment: That's... rather strange. That shouldn't happen?!

Answer (score 2):

## Linux C, 180 bytes code, 6336 bytes binary (gcc+strip x86_64)

```
#include<unistd.h>
char s[]="\rhello world";
int main(){int n;for(n=1;s[n]!=0;n++){if(s[n]>0x40)s[n]^=0x20;if(n>1)if(s[n-1]>0x40)s[n-1]^=0x20;write(1,&s,sizeof(s)-1);sleep(1);};};
```

Comment: Do you mind putting the byte count and language in the header? Formatting is like this: `# <Language>, <N> bytes`

Comment: You can golf a few bytes by changing `0x20` into `32`

Answer (score 2):

### AWK, 123 bytes

```
BEGIN{s="hello world\n"
split(s,a,"")
for(L=1;L<12;L++){for(m=1;m<13;m++)printf m==L?toupper(a[m]):a[m]
system("sleep 1")}}
```

Fairly standard `AWK` but it does require the availability of `sleep`.  On my `Linux` box the default argument to `sleep` is an integer number of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 137 bytes

```java
String q="HELLO WORLD";for(int x,i=0;i<132;System.out.print((char)(x>10?10:(x!=i/12?32:0)|q.charAt(x))))Thread.sleep((x=i++%12)<1?999:0);
```

Ungolfed and with comments:

```java
    String q = "HELLO WORLD"; // note that the string is 11 characters long
    for (int x, i = 0;
         i < 132; // 11 rows, 12 columns (one column for newlines)
         System.out.print((char) (x > 10 ? // if this is the last column
                 10 // print newline
                 : // else:
                 (x != i / 12 ? //check if column == row
                         32 : 0) | q.charAt(x)))) // de-capitalize
        Thread.sleep((x = i++ % 12) < 1 ? 999 : 0); // if this is the first column, wait almost 1 second.
    // the above line will also update i and x
```

Edit:
A full program would take 196 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 108 bytes

```
(let((a"hello world"))(dotimes(i 11)(format t"~a~c"(string-upcase a :start i :end(1+ i))#\return)(sleep 1)))
```

Works on a regular terminal, on [tio.run](https://tio.run/##BcExDsMwCADAryB3AVUdvOYtXZBDUyRiW0DULV9375ppzLXQJBG5fMVswG@47YUI95F6SqBCrYSf4ScnZLn5bgUjXfvxumbjEGDYItkTFDbpO9YnKNHj7ZKXd8IwkQmViNb6Aw) does not overwrite the string.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell 3.0, <s>72</s> 63 Bytes

<sup>-9 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>

```
0..10|%{cls;($s=[char[]]'hello world')[$_]-=32;-join$s;sleep 1}
```

Not too shabby.

Comment: It can to save some bytes `0..10|%{cls;($s=[char[]]'hello world')[$_]-=32;-join$s;sleep 1}`

Answer (score 1):

**Haskell** <s>**232**</s> **212** **Bytes**

The trickiest part was reliably implementing a delay using prelude. Control.Concurrent threadDelay could be used for a robust solution. I started with `delay n= foldr seq "\&" (drop n[5.5*10^6..10^7]` which works in the REPL, however does not work compiled into a .exe.

[image]

Golfed Version

```
d=[0..10]>>"\BS"
p=concat$replicate(2*10^5)" \BS"
l=zip['a'..'z']['A'..'Z']
t x=([u|(l,u)<-l,l==x]++" ")!!0
y(x:xs)e|length xs==12-e=t x:xs|1>0=x:(y xs e)
main = do mapM_ putStr$[y"hello world"x++p++d|x<-[2..12]]
```

Explanation:

```
--Create a row of backspaces. When sent to IO deletes last character
delrow= [0..10]>>"\BS"

--print beaucoup spaces and backspaces
printblank = concat $ replicate (200000)  (' ':"\BS")


--Helpers to create a caps letter
lowerandupper = zip (['a'..'z']) (['A'..'Z'])
toupper x = head ([u|(l,u)<-lowerandupper, l==x]++" ")
touppers (x:xs) elem | length xs == 12- elem = toupper x :xs
                   | 1>0 = x: (touppers xs elem)

main = do
        --use mapM_ to putStr for each element of list
        mapM_ putStr $ [touppers "hello world" x ++ printblank++delrow|x <-[2..12]]
```

Looking forward to comments, feedback and improvements.

@laikoni thanks for the inputs saving numerous bytes.

Comment: There appears to be an identifier `elem` in your golfed code which could be shortened. Also using line breaks instead of `;` results in the same byte count but slightly better readable code.

Comment: Instead of `delrow`, can't you just print a carriage return?

Comment: `(' ':"\BS")` is just `" \BS"`. You don't need parenthesis around lists. There is unnecessary whitespace in your main and I think you don't need the `do`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I was looking at that, but carriage return will start a new line. For example, `putStr "Hello world">>= \x -> (putStr "\r")>>= (\y  -> putStr "Hello world")` would return 2 lines:  Hello world
Hello world  whereas `putStr "Hello world">>= \x -> (putStr delrow)>>= (\y  -> putStr "Hello world")` returns just 1 line

Comment: It shouldn't. And why not just do `putStr "\rhello world"`?

Comment: The identifier `xs` can be shortened. You can omit the parenthesis in `x:(y xs e)`. Instead of comparing `e` to the length of the rest list it might be shorter to check if `e` is zero and decrement it in each recursive call. Your main can start with `main=mapM_ ...` and finally you can inline `d`, `p`, `l` and `e` because they are called only at one position each.

Answer (score 1):

## Rebol, 70 bytes

```
repeat n 11[prin[head uppercase/part at copy"hello world^M"n 1]wait 1]
```

Ungolfed:

```
repeat n 11 [
    prin [head uppercase/part at copy "hello world^M" n 1]
    wait 1
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java - 240 bytes

```
interface a{static void main(String[]a)throws Throwable{int x=1;char[]b="\rhello world".toCharArray();while(x<12){if(b[x]!=' ')b[x]=(char)((int)b[x]^32);System.out.print(b);Thread.sleep(1000);if(b[x]!=' ')b[x]=(char)((int)b[x]^32);x++;}}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
interface a {
    static void main(String[] a) throws Throwable {
        int x = 1;
        char[] b = "\rhello world".toCharArray();
        while(x < 12) {
            if (b[x] != ' ')
                b[x]=(char)((int)b[x]^32);
            System.out.print(b);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (b[x] != ' ')
                b[x]=(char)((int)b[x]^32);
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: GIF of it]

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 139 Bytes

```
() => {
    val a = "\033[H\033[2J\nhello world"
    8 to 19 map{c=>
        print(a.updated(c,a(c)toUpper))
        Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (MinGW), <s>83</s> <s>80</s> 77 bytes

Only tested on Windows.

`f(){for(char s[]="\rhello world",*t=s;*++t;*t+=32)*t-=32,printf(s),sleep(1);}`

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 56 bytes

```ruby
"hello world".gsub(/./){$><<?\r+$`+$&.upcase+$'
sleep 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 49 bytes

```perl
sleep say"chello world"^""x$_.$"x!/7/ for 2..12
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1qcqmCqZ2BoYP2/OCc1tUChOLFSSTo5IzUnJ1@hPL8oJ0UpTolBqUIlXk9FqUJR31xfIS2/SMFIT8/Q6P9/AA) - only really works in a terminal, but you can easily copy/paste from here.

### Explanation

This script uses the stringwise `XOR` operation to capitalise the needed letters in each iteration. First we build the string `'hello world'` (which includes `\x1bc` as an ANSI escape sequence to clear the screen), then we `XOR` (`^`) against a string of repeating `NUL` bytes (repeating as needed, 2 on the first iteration and finishing with 12), followed by a space (`$"`) on all but the 7th iteration (which would remove the space in the middle - well, set it to `NUL`).

Please note this script contains unprintables, here's a reversible hex dump:

```perl
00000000: 736c 6565 7020 7361 7922 1b63 6865 6c6c  sleep say".chell
00000010: 6f20 776f 726c 6422 5e22 0022 7824 5f2e  o world"^"."x$_.
00000020: 2422 7821 2f37 2f20 666f 7220 322e 2e31  $"x!/7/ for 2..1
00000030: 32                                       2
```

Answer (score 1):

## x86 opcode(.COM), 48 bytes

```
  org 100h
  mov ax, 0x0900
  mov bx, -34
  out 0x70,al
  mov dx, stri
  int 0x21
  push 0xa802
  pop ds
r:in  al,0x71
  cmp al,cl
  jz  r
  xchg ax,cx
  xor [bx],dword 0x200020
  add bx, 2
  jnz r
  stri db 'hello world$'
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Small Basic](http://www.smallbasic.com), 166 bytes

Takes no input and outputs to the `TextWindow`.

```
For i=1To 11
l=0
t="hello world
p()
l=i-1
t=Text.GetSubText("HELLO WORLD",i,1)
p()
Program.Delay(1000)
EndFor
Sub p
TextWindow.CursorLeft=l
TextWindow.Write(t)
EndSub
```

[Try it at SmallBasic.com!](http://www.smallbasic.com/program?DKQ101) *Requires Silverlight/IE*

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 103 bytes

```forth
: f s" hello world"11 0 do page over dup i type i + dup c@ toupper emit 1+ over i - type 1000 ms loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU3LCoAgEPyVoWsEeq1LvxK6lmDsolb09bXlZYZ5MYFz3YY1fPSMkGUluIwJI6wxRgGT@gGlw0YpMS7OyXfWwsBzG/BJGf4QRNRbSKn/pZtR@RDRlPZYYftWjRha8b/YCxKz6E94Xg)

Doesn't work properly in TIO, but if you copy and paste into a gforth interpreter/terminal you get a proper animation.

I overwrote `page` and `1000` in the tio header so the output was readable and didn't take 10+ seconds to render, but the value in the "code" box is correct

#### Explanation

Loops through all characters in "hello world". For each one:

- Clear screen and set cursor to top left of terminal/window
- Output all characters before the current one
- Output the current character uppercase (or as-is for space)
- Output all characters after the current one
- Wait 1 sec (1000 milliseconds)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                 \ start a new word definition
  s" hello world"   \ create a string containing "hello world"
  11 0              \ set up loop parameters
  do                \ loop from 0 to 10 inclusive
    page            \ clear the screen/terminal and set cursor to top left
    over            \ get the string's starting address
    dup i type      \ output the first i characters of the string
    i + dup c@      \ get the value at the address of the current character
    toupper emit    \ convert to uppercase and output
    1+ over i -     \ add 1 to address, subtract current index from string length
    type            \ output end of string
    1000 ms         \ wait 1 seconds
  loop              \ end loop
;                   \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▒4↓σ┘«☼⌡♥Åα≡♂%Ç$K¥╞▲▓►
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b13419e5d9ae0ff5038fe0f00b2580244b9dc61eb210&i=)

delaying takes a lotta bytes.

Answer (score 0):

**PowerShell, 76 bytes**

```
$b= # The solution is the next line
{$a=[char[]]$_;1..$a.length|%{$a[--$_]-=32;cls;-join$a;$a[$_]-=-32;sleep 1}}
'hello world'|% $b
```

Answer (score 0):

## ES2015, 126 bytes

Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109929/76430) answer.

```js
c=console;d=0;t=_=>setTimeout(_=>{a=[...`hello world`];a[d]?c.clear(a[d]=a[d++].toUpperCase())|t(c.log(a.join``)):a},1e3);t()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 104 bytes

```
Monitor[Do[s=y=Characters@"hello world";s=s~Delete~i;Pause@1,{i,11}],""<>Insert[s,Capitalize[y][[i]],i]]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 217 bytes

```cs
using u=System.Console;class P{static string a="hello world";static void Main(){for(int i=0;i<11;i++){u.Clear();u.WriteLine(a.Substring(0,i)+char.ToUpper(a[i])+a.Substring(i+1));System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BasMwEER/ReQkoUbIZ8WnXFMoOCWHkMNG3sQLqmS0Uksw/nYnpT70Nrx5DON569kvS2WKd1Hb7sEFv8w@RU4BnQ/ALD4mLlDICy75V4N2M2AISfykHPqNW9vvRL14B4pSTbeUJcUiqLWOdk3jSGs1VbMPCFkqV80pU8EDRZRgunr9m5b2jZT2A2RzTJ/jiFnCmS5K/3dIN0q59elxyAj9C6/JdAFxlI21Vrl5npflCQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 161 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char;import System.IO;main=mapM(\x->do putStr$('\b'<$z)++[(toUpper v:(v<$z))!!abs(k-x)|(v,k)<-zip"hello world"z];hWaitForInput stdin 1000)z;z=[0..10]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't quite work in TIO.