# Print Leonardo DiCaprio without using any of the letters in his name

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The Oscars are coming up soon and we all know who's going to win Best Actor in a Leading Role this year right? The great Leonardo DiCaprio of course! Despite his superb performances in all of his films during his career, he has yet to win an Academy Award. So as tribute and as a way to wish him luck during the Awards Ceremony this year, your task is to print "Leonardo DiCaprio" (without quotes and case-sensitive) without using any letters in his name in your code. This is code-golf so the shortest code wins. Score is based on your code in bytes. Any language is acceptable.

**-100 Points** if you can print his name on an `ascii` plate like so (Best Actor not required):

```
 _____________________________
|                             |
|      Leonardo DiCaprio      |
|         Best Actor          |
|_____________________________|
```

**Edit** For clarification, the rule for not "using any letters in his name in your code" is  **case-insensitive**.

Also **another edit** you may use spaces.

Comment: `without using any letters in his name in your code` Is this rule case-insensitive?

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, it's case-insensitive.

Comment: I should have phrase my question clearer. Do you allow lowercase `c`, or is it forbidden since uppercase `C` is in his name?

Comment: Case insensitive meaning I can use `lEO...` or cannot?

Comment: @Quincunx Case insensitive meaning you cannot use  LlEeOoNnAaRrDdOoIiCcPp

Comment: Is correct case required in the output? Which of the following are acceptable? 1. Leonardo DiCaprio 2.LEONARDO DICAPRIO 3.leonardo dicaprio 4.Something random like lEONardo dicAPRIo

Comment: @steveverrill Correct case required.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why the techniques used in [Obfuscated Hello World](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/307/obfuscated-hello-world) shouldn't work for this too, making it a duplicate.

Comment: Perhaps should have said "in a manner which actually uses English letters somewhere"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Esolang regardless, most normal languages won't able to print anything when only the vowel `u` is allowed. Heck, even declaring `main` is not allowed.

Comment: <iframe src="http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21499"></iframe>

Answer (score 14):

### J, 54 - 100 = -46

```
<17$3(3!:4)8026666198671254860 7598259084372558880 111
```

Output:

```
┌─────────────────┐
│Leonardo DiCaprio│
└─────────────────┘
```

Comment: "like so" was the request.

Comment: This can be trimmed down by using base-36 encoding of the long integers, reducing each with 3 characters.

Comment: @jpjacobs I think base-36 would use some of the letters that aren't permitted.

Comment: Ah sure, I totally forgot that rule, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

### HTML/Markdown, 96 bytes

```
&#76;&#101;&#111;&#110;&#97;&#114;&#100;&#111;&#32;&#68;&#105;&#67;&#97;&#112;&#114;&#105;&#111;
```

This works even with the strictest rule (no space, no letter case-insensitive).

### Markdown, 194 - 100 = 94 bytes

This is the fancy version, so it uses quite a lot of bytes (UTF-8). At the end of the first 2 lines are 2 spaces.

```
╔════════════╗  
║&#76;&#101;&#111;&#110;&#97;&#114;&#100;&#111;&#32;&#68;&#105;&#67;&#97;&#112;&#114;&#105;&#111;║  
╚════════════╝
```

How it looks (may or may not look good depending on the font face):

╔════════════╗
║Leonardo DiCaprio║
╚════════════╝

### Markdown, 142 - 100 = 42 bytes

This is the poor man's version. No Unicode character is used, so quite lightweight.

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
| &#76;&#101;&#111;&#110;&#97;&#114;&#100;&#111;&#32;&#68;&#105;&#67;&#97;&#112;&#114;&#105;&#111; |  
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It looks like a cookie to me:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| Leonardo DiCaprio |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: "like so" was the request. Three outputs each different in format but not as required is fun, though.

Comment: @BillWoodger: Most answers here don't even follow OP's format.

Answer (score 5):

## BF, 77

203 chars = 609 bits = 77 bytes

```
-[------->+<]>+++.-[--->++++<]>+.++++++++++.-.-------------.--[--->+<]>---.--------------.+++++++++++.[--->+<]>-----.++[->++<]>.++[-->+++<]>.++[->+++<]>++.-[-->+++<]>--.-[++>-----<]>.++.---------.++++++.
```

Output:

```
Leonardo DiCaprio
```

Answer (score 4):

### Sclipting, 39 bytes

```
丟냆녯닦굲뉆묠끆땃눗걲늖및
```

Based on the Hello, world! program, just encode the name as string.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 221 - 100 = 121

This took a little working out... instead of printing, it pushes the result as an `alert`... best I could do... trying to make this code do a `document.write` would have floored me...

`3[z=(y=''+{})[5]+y[1]+(''+1/0)[1]+'st'+(x=''+!0)[1]+'u'+y[5]+'t'+y[1]+x[1]][z]("\141\154\145\162t('"+(v="+--------------------+")+"\\\156|\114\145\157\156\141\162\144\157 \104\151\103\141\160\162\151\157|\\\156"+v+"')")()`